# Does if generate support else?

Tags: vhdl

I've been searching but couldn't find any useful information so I guess it's not supported...

I have a construct like

```
SIGNAL container : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR((2*total)-1 DOWNTO 0);
SIGNAL storage : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(total-1 DOWNTO 0);
copy : FOR a in 0 to total-1 GENERATE
    first_set : IF a < 10 GENERATE
        storage(a)  <= container(a);
    END GENERATE;
    second_set : IF a > 9 GENERATE
        storage(a)  <= container(a+10);
    END GENERATE;
END GENERATE;
```

So I'd like to concatenate two subvectors into a new one, but is there a way to use `ELSE` if the `first_set` condition is `False`?
Something like

```
SIGNAL container : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR((2*total)-1 DOWNTO 0);
SIGNAL storage : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(total-1 DOWNTO 0);
copy : FOR a in 0 to total-1 GENERATE
    first_set : IF a < 10 GENERATE
        storage(a)  <= container(a);
    ELSE
        storage(a)  <= container(a+10);
    END GENERATE;
END GENERATE;
```

Comment: Okay, I was a little bit puzzled because of https://github.com/ghdl/ghdl/issues/106

Comment: I'm using VHDL 2008, so I'll do it with two separate `if generate` statements

Comment: @Eugene Sh it was added in vhdl2008. Some tools were slow to support but it is now generally supported

Comment: @Tricky You are right, sorry for misleading comments. The actual [standard document](ftp://ftp.lpp.polytechnique.fr/jeandet/keep/sync/vhdl/4772740_IEEE-1076_Standard-VHDL-Language-Ref-Manual.pdf) is listing it as supported (page 182).

Comment: he syntax of an if generate statement else alternative doesn't match that found in the 'Something like' snippet (see IEEE Std 1076-2008 11.8 Generate statements). Absent the declarations for total, storage, and container there's no compelling reason a for generate statement can't be used without the if generate and it's else alternative in the sample snippet. As shown in ghdl issue 106 generate statements else alternatives are supported, easily verified with a practicable example.  Note 0 to total is one more than total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If..elsif..else generate was added in vhdl 2008. Case..generate was also added.